# insertAtRank Vector algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I'm trying to write a program for college to insert elements into a vector-based array. However, my `insertAtRank` and `removeAtRank` methods don't appear to be working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class ArrayVector implements Vector {

    int n ; 
    Object[] A ; 
    Object element  ; 

    public ArrayVector() {
        A = new Object[10] ; 
        n = 0 ; 
    }

    public int size() {
        return n;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return n == 0;
    }

    public Object elemAtRank(int rank) throws RankOutOfBoundsException {
        return A[rank];
    }

    public Object replaceAtRank(int rank, Object element) throws RankOutOfBoundsException {
        A[rank] = element ; 
        return element;
    }

    public String toString() {
        int size = size();
        String output = "" + size + "\t";

        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
            output += A[i] + " ";
        }
        return output;
    }

    public void insertAtRank(int rank, Object element) throws RankOutOfBoundsException {
        for ( int i = n   ; i < rank ; n--){
            A[i] = A[i+1] ; 
        }
        A[rank] = element ; 
        n++ ; 
    }

    public Object removeAtRank(int rank) throws RankOutOfBoundsException {
        element = A[rank]; 
        for ( int i = rank ; i < n-2 ; rank++){
            A[i] = A[i+1] ; 
        }
        n = n-1 ; 
        return element ; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RankOutOfBoundsException {
        ArrayVector newArray = new ArrayVector() ; 

        System.out.println (newArray.toString()) ;
        newArray.insertAtRank(0, "c");
        System.out.println (newArray.toString()) ; 
        newArray.insertAtRank(1, "a");
        System.out.println (newArray.toString()) ; 
        newArray.removeAtRank(0) ; 
        System.out.println (newArray.toString()) ; 
        newArray.insertAtRank(2, "t");
        System.out.println (newArray.toString()) ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: why aren't your satisfied with the built-in vector? what do you want to do for the two methods? what is a `rank` in your context?

Comment: it's a homework assignment, so i'm guessing he cannot use the java.util.Vector class.

Comment: Why not using ArrayList<Object>? Do u need a sync? How u will use it? What kind of data growth you need? x2 or x1.5?

Comment: also, you do not mention "what" the actual failure is.  are you getting a stack trace?  or just anomalous behavior?

Comment: Lel. Just read that its a homework assignment :p

Comment: @him I read `college` as `colleague` ....

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Our assignment was to add methods to the provided headers, so we can't use any Java built in utilities. Thanks for all the comments though!The issue is that it outputs errors mainly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fellow...
Heres what you need:

```
public class MyVectorInsertingLel{

    private static Object[] objects;
    private static int n;

     public static void main(String []args){
        MyVectorInsertingLel v = new MyVectorInsertingLel(10);
        v.insertObject("c");
     }

     public MyVectorInsertingLel(int initialHeap)
     {
         n = 0;
         objects = new Object[initialHeap];
     }

     public void insertObject(Object obj)
     {
         n++;
         if (n > objects.length)
         {
            Object[] temp = objects.clone();
            objects = new Object[objects.length*2];
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, objects, 0, temp.length);
         }
         objects[n] = obj;
     }

}
```

"insert elements into a vector-based array" - Vector-based understood as extendable...
As you didnt say "remove" or anything else, no reason to be mad :3 Really. This is an answer!

Comment: It got flagged for review, and that's where that message came from. Try not to post an answer with no content only to edit in content later. Use the preview in the editor to clean up/format everything the way you want it then save it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however we must use the classes given.